# How to update the image of rancher container with go program

Tags: go

Thank you for reading. I'm chinese. I have problem with rancher. I want to use golang to make a program that I can click one time to push image to the right place and restart the test environment.

I’m new hand to learn golang. I tried to use golang connect linux. But I can't do more works about it. I have no idea. I find a code from internet in China.

```
// connect to ssh
addr = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port)

if client, err = ssh.Dial("tcp", addr, clientConfig); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// create session
if session, err = client.NewSession(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return session, nil
```

I want to learn how to make the program or some people can provide golang write plugins to help me. Thanks again!

Comment: Do I understand that you want to push an image over an existing ssh connection?

Comment: docker，rancher，Jenkins has greatly simplified the operation of project deployment. Our manager has put forward a requirement that I use go to do one-click operations, including code packaging and push mirroring. Again, it's easy for colleagues to waste time in this part.